# "get" method is returning an empty string when that string has a value

Tags: java, user-input

I have a method that, among many things, gets an input from a JTextField.  I need to use that input in another class so I created a getOutput() method which returns the input string.  The only problem is that it returns an empty string `""`.

Prompt class:  This class creates a window with the JTextField in it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Prompt {
    private final String title;
    private final String promptstr;
    private String myInput;

    public Prompt() {
        title = "";
        promptstr = "";
        myInput = "";
    }

    public Prompt(String title, String prompt) {
        this.title = title;
        promptstr = prompt;
        myInput = "";
    }

    public void createPrompt() {
        JFrame pwindow = new JFrame(title);
        pwindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel main = new JPanel();
        main.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        JPanel input = new JPanel();
        input.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        input.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));


        JLabel prompt = new JLabel(promptstr);
        input.add(prompt);

        JTextField in = new JTextField(25);
        input.add(in);

        JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
        buttons.add(ok);
        ok.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            myInput = in.getText();
            try (FileWriter output = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\output.txt"))) {
//                function here
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
            pwindow.dispose();
        });

        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        buttons.add(cancel);
        cancel.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            try (FileWriter output = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\output.txt"))) {
//                function here
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
            pwindow.dispose();
        });

        main.add(input);
        main.add(buttons);

        pwindow.getContentPane();
        pwindow.add(main);
        pwindow.pack();
        pwindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return myInput;
    }
}
```

Below is the Menu class where I try to print the JTextField input using the getOutput() method from the class above.

```
package japp1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Menu {
    public Menu() {
        //do something
    }

    public JMenuBar createCalcMenu() {
        JMenuBar calcmenu = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        calcmenu.add(fileMenu);
        calcmenu.add(editMenu);

        JMenuItem newAction = new JMenuItem("New");
        JMenuItem openAction = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem exitAction = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        JMenuItem cutAction = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        JMenuItem copyAction = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        JMenuItem pasteAction = new JMenuItem("Paste");

        JCheckBoxMenuItem checkAction = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Check Action");

        JRadioButtonMenuItem radioAction1 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Radio Button 1");
        JRadioButtonMenuItem radioAction2 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Radio Button 2");

        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(radioAction1);
        bg.add(radioAction2);
        fileMenu.add(newAction);
        fileMenu.add(openAction);
        fileMenu.add(checkAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exitAction);
        editMenu.add(cutAction);
        editMenu.add(copyAction);
        editMenu.add(pasteAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(radioAction1);
        editMenu.add(radioAction2);

        //actionevents
        exitAction.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            System.exit(0); 
        });

        return calcmenu;
    }

    public JMenuBar createPlotMenu() {
        JMenuBar plotmenu = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu plot = new JMenu("Plot");
        plotmenu.add(file);
        plotmenu.add(plot);

        //file items
        JMenuItem newAction = new JMenuItem("New Function");
        JMenu clearAction = new JMenu("Clear");
        JMenuItem exitAction = new JMenu("Exit");
        ArrayList<JMenuItem> funcs = new ArrayList<>();

        //plot items

        file.add(newAction);
        file.add(clearAction);
        file.addSeparator();
        file.add(exitAction);

        //actionevents
        newAction.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            Prompt nf = new Prompt("Add a new function","f(x)=");
            nf.createPrompt();
            System.out.println(nf.getOutput());
        });

        exitAction.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            System.exit(0);
        });

        return plotmenu;
    }
}
```

Its probably worth noting that neither of these classes are finished, so some of the comments and empty constructors won't stay that way.

Comment: Can you remove the code not relevant to your question? See [mcve] for an explanation of why this helps us.

Comment: In support of @JohnKugelman's suggestion, you might try to recreate the situation locally with the minimal set of code necessary (which is what John wanted to see here) as that might help you work through what's going on. This means go create a new class or two and just get it to do what is necessary to recreate (or not) your situation.

Comment: Since your `createPrompt()` creates and opens a `JFrame` rather than a modal `JDialog`, it returns immediately after opening the window. By that time, no-one has neither entered text nor clicked on OK, thus `getOutput()` correctly returns the initial empty string by that time. You have to wait for the window being closed before querying the string value.

Comment: Use a JOptionPane or modal JDialog. Because you're inappropriately showing a JFrame, you're calling `getOutput()` before the user has had a chance to input anything. Look for yourself -- the blank output is displayed before your prompt window has been disposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing code like you might for a console (or procedural) API, GUI's don't work this way.

Let's start with your entry point...

```
newAction.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    Prompt nf = new Prompt("Add a new function","f(x)=");
    nf.createPrompt();
    System.out.println(nf.getOutput());
});
```

Nothing particularly wrong with this, but if we have a look at `createPrompt`...

```
public void createPrompt() {
    JFrame pwindow = new JFrame(title);
```

The first thing you do is create a `JFrame`, this is going to be a problem, as a `JFrame` doesn't "block" the current execution of code when it's made visible, instead, if returns (almost) immediately, meaning that the `createPrompt` method will return and you evaluate the `getOutput` method before the user's even had a chance to make a selection.

Instead, you should use a modal dialog.  This will block the code's execution at the point where the dialog is made visible and will continue to block it until the dialog is closed (this is all done in a manner which won't actually block the Event Dispatching Thread, so the UI won't appear "dead")

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

There are a number of ways you might do this, but I like to use a single method to show the prompt and return the result, something like this, as an example...

```
public String showPrompt(JComponent owner) {
    JDialog pwindow = new JDialog(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(owner), title, Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    main.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    JPanel input = new JPanel();
    input.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    input.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

    JLabel prompt = new JLabel(promptstr);
    input.add(prompt);

    JTextField in = new JTextField(25);
    input.add(in);

    JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
    buttons.add(ok);
    ok.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        myInput = in.getText();
        try (FileWriter output = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\output.txt"))) {
            //function here
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        pwindow.dispose();
    });

    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    buttons.add(cancel);
    cancel.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        try (FileWriter output = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Mike\\Desktop\\output.txt"))) {
            //function here
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        pwindow.dispose();
    });

    main.add(input);
    main.add(buttons);

    pwindow.getContentPane();
    pwindow.add(main);
    pwindow.pack();
    pwindow.setVisible(true);

    return myInput;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. He should use a JOptionPane or modal dialog.

Comment: Didn't I say that at the end?